# Derivative application question

Tags: applications

A girl of height $120 $cm is walking towards a light on the ground at a speed of $0.6$ m/s. Her shadow is being cast on a wall behind her that is $5 $m from the light. 
How is the size of her shadow changing when she is $1.5$ m from the light?

Not sure what to do here, if someone could help me out that would be fantasic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l(t)$ be the distance between the girl and the light changing with time and  $h(t)$ be the hight of her shadow.

You can get that $$\dfrac {l(t)}{5}=\dfrac{1.2}{h(t)} \implies 6=l.h$$

By taking derivative with respect to $t$

$$0=l_th+lh_t$$ and we know that $l_t=-0.6$ and $l=1.5 \implies h=4$

$$0=-0.6\times4+1.5\times h_t \implies h_t=\dfrac{8}{5} $$

**Note:** The first equation can be got by the properties of similiar triangles and I used the notation $x_t$ as $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$. We take $l_t=-0.6$ but not $0.6$ since the girl is approaching the light so $l(t)$ is decreasing.

Comment: How is a product of two changeable functions is constant ?

Comment: it is like $t$ and $1\over t$ ...

Comment: is that works for any kind of functions ?

Comment: thx for the help!

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: @Antaraz:  Actually, we can find $l(t)$ explicitly like $l(t)=1.5-0.6t$ (by asuming when $t=0$ it is on desired point) but we do not need it. Witout finding $l$ and $h$ we can compute the $h_t$ when $l=1.5$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume she is $x$ m from the light. Find the height of your shadow in terms of $x$ using similar triangles.

Differentiate it with respect to $t$ where $t$ is time. Use $dx/dt=\text{speed of girl}$